# ASP.NET MVC : how to create razor view form dynamically at run time according to html details stored in database table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Screenshot of table structure with data**
[image]
Table structure is as below:

```
Id | Category | DisplayName | FieldName | FieldType | FieldLength | IsRequired
```

Please see screenshot for details.

On selection of a category all HTML fields defined in table against that category should populate in view.

And how to validate on form submit.

I have more than 400 categories.

Comment: Query the database (probably using paging with Skip() and Take()), put the results in a ViewModel and iterate over that model in your view, printing its properties. What have you tried?

Comment: First, select all the categories from the db, Second, in you view, use a for loop and loop through the result from the db, Third, use a switch case statement to properly render the correct input fields. letmme know if you don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I think you can do.

First declare a `class` call it any name, I will use `SampleClass`

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldType { get; set; }
    public string FieldLength { get; set; }
    public int IsRequired { get; set; }//you can convert this to boolean to make it easier
}
```

Secondly, populate this class from the db in the Controller

```
//assuming you are using linq query
var allEntry = context.Table.Where(m => m.Category == SelectedCategory);
var allViews = new List<SampleClass>();
foreach (var entry in allEntry)
{
    allViews.Add(new SampleClass
    {
        FieldName = entry.FieldName,
        //and so on...

    });
}
```

Third and in the view do this as I said in the comment

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "forms-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Title of the form</h4>
        <hr /><br />
        @foreach (var a in List<SampleClass>)//note this(List<SampleClass>) will be passed from the controller to the view.
        {
            switch (a.FieldType)
             {
                case "Test":
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="@a.FieldName"></label>
                        <input id="@a.FieldName" type="text" name="@a.FieldName" required="@(a.IsRequired == 1 ? "required" : "")" />
                    </div>
                    break;
                case "Number":
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="@a.FieldName"></label>
                        <input id="@a.FieldName" type="number" name="@a.FieldName" required="@(a.IsRequired == 1 ? "required" : "")" />
                    </div>
                    break;
                case "Select":
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="@a.FieldName"></label>
                        @Html.DropDownList(a.FieldName, new SelectList(DbUtils.GetEvaluations(), "Value", "Text", null), "Select..", new { @required = @a.IsRequired == 1 ? "required" : "" })
                    </div>
                    break;
            }
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

You can have more `cases` in your select clause depending on what you need.

Hope this helps..